# Convert pcl point type XYZ to Eigen Vector 4f

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, eigenvector

I am trying to convert pcl pointXYZ to eigen vector

```
Eigen::Vector4f min (minPnt.x, minPnt.y, minPnt.z);  
Eigen::Vector4f max (maxPnt.x, maxPnt.y, maxPnt.z);
```

where minPnt and maxPnt are of type pcl::PointXYZ. 
However, I get an error as "error C2338: THIS_METHOD_IS_ONLY_FOR_VECTORS_OF_A_SPECIFIC_SIZE" . Could you suggest some other approaches or let me know if my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 12):

Please use `getVector4fMap()` to get `Eigen::Vector4f` and use `getVector3fMap()` to get `Eigen::Vector3f`

Example:

```cpp
PointT pcl_pt = ...;
Eigen::Vector3f e_v3f_pt = pcl_pt.getVector3fMap();
Eigen::Vector4f e_v4f_pt = pcl_pt.getVector4fMap();
```

If what you have is a `pcl::Normal`, you can try to use `getNormalVector4fMap` as shown below

```cpp
pcl::Normal pcl_normal(0, 0, 1);
Eigen::Vector4f eigen_normal = pcl_normal.getNormalVector4fMap();
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the above problem with following code.

```
auto x_min = static_cast<float>(minPnt.x); 
auto y_min = static_cast<float>(minPnt.y); 
auto z_min = static_cast<float>(minPnt.z); 

auto x_max = static_cast<float>(maxPnt.x); 
auto y_max = static_cast<float>(maxPnt.y); 
auto z_max = static_cast<float>(maxPnt.z); 

Eigen::Vector4f min(x_min, y_min, z_min, 0.0); 
Eigen::Vector4f max(x_max, y_max, z_max, 0.0);
```

If there is better approach , please suggest .

Answer (score 2):

`eigen::Vector4f` is looking for 4 floats, but you only gave it 3 (x, y, z).  try adding a 0 at the end:

```cpp
Eigen::Vector4f min (minPnt.x, minPnt.y, minPnt.z, 0);  
Eigen::Vector4f max (maxPnt.x, maxPnt.y, maxPnt.z, 0);
```

Comment: Or a 1 if you're using (x,y,z,w) coordinates